# Nuxt: Fetching data only on server side

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering

I am using Github's API to fetch the list of my pinned repositories, and I put the call in the AsyncData method so that I have the list on the first render. But I just learnt that AsyncData is called once on ServerSide, then everytime the page is loaded on the client. That means that the client no longer has the token to make API calls, and anyways, I wouldn't let my Github token in the client.

And when I switch page (from another page to the page with the list) the data is not there I just have the default empty array

I can't figure out what is the best way to be sure that my data is always loaded on server side ?

```ts
export default defineComponent({
  name: 'Index',
  components: { GithubProject, Socials },
  asyncData(context: Context) {
    return context.$axios.$post<Query<UserPinnedRepositoriesQuery>>('https://api.github.com/graphql', {
      query,
    }, {
      headers: {
        // Token is defined on the server, but not on the client
        Authorization: `bearer ${process.env.GITHUB_TOKEN}`,
      },
    })
      .then((data) => ({ projects: data.data.user.pinnedItems.nodes }))
      .catch(() => {});
  },
  setup() {
    const projects = ref<Repository[]>([]);

    return {
      projects,
    };
  },
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use Vuex with `nuxtServerInit`.

`nuxtServerInit` will fire always on first page load no matter on what page you are. So you should navigate first to `store/index.js`.

After that you create an state:

```js
export const state = () => ({
  data: []
})
```

Now you create the action that is always being executed whenever you refresh the page. Nuxt have access to the store even if its on the server side.

Now you need to get the data from the store in your component:

```js
export const actions = {
  async nuxtServerInit ({ state }, { req }) {
    let response = await axios.get("some/path/...");
    state.data = response.data;
  }
}
```

You can store your token in an cookie. Cookies are on the client side but the `nuxtServerInit` has an second argument. The request `req`. With that you are able to access the headers and there is your cookie aswell.

`let cookie = req.headers.cookie;`

Comment: There is no authentication required, the request will always be the same, no matter who, no matter where. I need to try your solution, I think this is what I needed.

Comment: You can also store the API token in the store. when u navigate between pages the store wont lose his state. Only if you refresh the page the store will refresh

Comment: Is the store available to the user when inspecting ? This is a personnal access token to Github's API, not my own platform token.

Comment: the store is technically inspectable because its on the client side... because `nuxtServerInit` is on the server side you can use `env` variables

Comment: Alright, I already use env variables for the token. Putting the token in the store is way too risky and may result in an anticipated token expiracy.

Comment: i am not quite sure but you should be able to access your variables like this `process.env` in the `nuxtServerInit` function

Comment: Exactly this way :)

Answer (score 5):

Wrap your request in `if(process.server)` within the `asyncData` method of the page.

If you absolutely require the server-side to call and cannot do it from the client side, then you can just manipulate the `location.href` to force the page to do a full load.

Comment: That's indeed a solution, but I'm just catching the error and not doing anything, that's the same. My problem here is that If I navigate onto this page, I don't have the data. I really need the server to make this request, not the server

Comment: @nook Then you're going to need to use `location.href=/my-page` instead of using Vue router, so it forces a hard load.

Comment: Obviously. So simple that I forgot that. A basic anchor should do the work though. Please update your answer so I can validate it