# With Vue and the Nuxt store, how do I fetch from API on build, but not ever by the client?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, static-site

I'm using Vue and Nuxt  and want to pull data into my build that is mostly static. Each time we build the site, we want to get the latest data and then never call the API again. The data does not need to be updated dynamically, it just needs to be available for the app and can be built in.

One of the problems is that the call to get the API data is long (>5 seconds) and we don't want the customer waiting.

Our thinking was to

1. Call an API at some point in the build process to collect the data
2. Save the data in the store so other components can access it.
3. Not call the API to get the data again.

How might I do this? I really appreciate any help, I'm pretty new to Vue and especially Nuxt, but really enjoy both.

**What I've tried**
My understanding is that using fetch() in a component will call both on the server before the initial page is rendered and on the client some time after the component is mounted.

From the [documentation on Nuxt](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/features/data-fetching/)

> fetch is a hook called during server-side rendering after the
> component instance is created, and on the client when navigating. The
> fetch hook should return a promise (whether explicitly, or implicitly
> using async/await) that will be resolved:
>
> On the server before the initial page is rendered On the client some
> time after the component is mounted

I've also tried this approach (and am currently using it) [from Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61359791/4971361)

```js
export const actions = {
  async nuxtServerInit ({ state }, { req }) {
    let response = await axios.get("some/path/...");
    state.data = response.data;
  }
}
```

But there is a caveat in the answer:

> nuxtServerInit will fire always on first page load no matter on what page you are. So you should navigate first to store/index.js.

Anyway, I could use a hand figuring out how to do this.

Comment: How much data? I’ve exported data from a db and included it in the build as a json file, it works well if the file is a reasonable size. Otherwise fetch is the way to go, your understanding is a little off— if I refresh a page component that uses fetch, it’ll run the fetch hook once, on the server side. If I arrive in my app on another page but then navigate to the page that has the fetch call, the fetch will run once on the client side. Make sense?

Comment: @NickDawes Data is about 12,000 line JSON. We considered exporting it separately and saving it as a static JSON in the file, but we are looking for a way to not have a manual step. Was hoping to trigger the API pull on commit or on build.